# Event broadcasting in Laravel 5.2 with Redis and Socket.io

Tags: node.js, websocket, redis, socket.io, laravel-5

I updated Laravel 5.1 to 5.2 and the event is not broadcasting anymore.

I am using Laravel homestead with php 7 and hhvm, Node 5.3.0, Redis 3.0.6.

Redis is working fine. (I tried Redis::publish).

I fired the event but I do not get any message.

**Event class**

```
namespace App\Events;

use App\Events\Event;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;

class UserSignedUp extends Event implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use SerializesModels;

    public $username;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($username)
    {print_r($username);
        $this->username = $username;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should be broadcast on.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return ['test-channel'];
    }
}
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('event', function () {
    $data = [
        'event' => 'UserSignedUp',
        'data' => [
            'username' => 'JohnDoe'
        ]
    ];

// Works fine
    Redis::publish('test-channel', json_encode($data));

// It does not broadcast anything
    event(new \App\Events\UserSignedUp('JohnDoe'));
});
```

**Socket.io server**

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var Redis = require('ioredis');
var redis = new Redis();

redis.subscribe('test-channel', function (err, count) {
});

redis.on('message', function (channel, message) {
    console.log('Message Recieved: ' + message);

    message = JSON.parse(message);

    io.emit(channel + ':' + message.event, message.data);
});

http.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Listening on Port 3000');
});
```

**Env config**

```
CACHE_DRIVER=redis
SESSION_DRIVER=redis
QUEUE_DRIVER=redis
BROADCAST_DRIVER=redis

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

every events that are fired, are pushed in the redis queue, to broadcast you must release the job in the queue, you can use the

`php artisan queue:listen ....`

or

`php artisan queue:work`

command

Comment: Hello there! I am facing the same issue with Laravel 5.3. I tried `php artisan queue:work` and `php artisan queue:listen` but none of them worked. As drd stated  `event(new \App\Events\TestEvent());` doesn't broadcast anything. Any other recommendation?